# How can I move a loadCategories() func from SomeViewController to SomeViewModel?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have the following function:

```
var categoryArray: [Category] = []

private func loadCategories() {

    downloadCategoriesFromFirebase { (allCategories) in

      self.categoryArray = allCategories
      self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

that is currently in my SomeViewController. I need to move it to SomeViewModel.

Sorry if my question is not well formulated, please do ask if you need any more information since I am so new at all this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reference to `SomeViewModel` in your `SomeViewController`, you can move the code over there.

For example:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
    private var viewModel: ViewModel!
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        callToViewModel()
    }
    
    func callToViewModel() {
        viewModel.loadCategories {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    // rest of your code 
}
```

The ViewModel could look something like this:

```swift
import Foundation

class ViewModel: NSObject {
    
    var categoryArray: [Category] = []

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    func loadCategories(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        downloadCategoriesFromFirebase { (allCategories) in
            self.categoryArray = allCategories
            completion?()
        }
    }
}
```

When reloading your data, make sure to refer to `viewModel.categoryArray` instead of `self.categoryArray` now.

Please notice that I'm making use of a completion handler to notify the `ViewController` the call in the `ViewModel` was finished. There are other (perhaps better) ways to do this, like the [Combine framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine).